# Adding Rows in Google Fusion Tables

Tags: random, addition, rows, google-fusion-tables

Just a quick question, everytime I hit "edit" "add row" it adds the row but not at the bottom of the table, it usually places it like 5-10 rows from the bottom and while it's not a huge deal it's just time consuming to move it and confusing at times because they're random rows all over now. Is their a setting or a certain way to add rows so they just get added to the bottom of the fusion table instead of randomly throughout?

Answer (score 1):

The rows will not be displayed randomly.

They will be displayed based on the order-settings.

When you didn't define a sort-column they will be ordered by their internal rowID, and that's the issue: the rowID's are not consecutive.

So the answer is: No, you can't.

The only workaround would be to add another column with a incrementing Number(and sort by this column), but I wouldn't suggest it.